# Bluetooth protocol question

Tags: bluetooth, mouse

It is my intention to make my own bluetooth mouse.

What is the protocol like? For starts I won't be making my own hardware but will be using an emulator.

What emulator do you suggest I use, and is there any documentation on the web that could direct me to making this successful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to Bluetooth (as opposed to a typical mouse protocol), then it's a large and complex standard with many [protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_protocols)/modes, rather like like USB.

[image: BT Layout]

Like USB, it has an [HID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Human_Interface_Device_Profile_.28HID.29) (Human Interface Device - [bt.org link](https://www.bluetooth.org/Building/HowTechnologyWorks/ProfilesAndProtocols/HID.htm)) profile, which is used for mice, keyboards, game controllers, pointing devices, etc.
There is also the [RFCOMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_protocols#Radio_frequency_communication_.28RFCOMM.29) mode you may want to look at, which essentially emulates a serial port like RS232. You can obtain cheap and easy to use modules that can act as a server or client in this mode (e.g. I have used one here in a prototype device, purchased from eBay for ~£5 in a quantity of 5)

All the major vendors like Digikey, Mouser, Farnell do various BT modules. Also, as mentioned, have a look on eBay for "Bluetooth Module HC-05".

Comment: Your link to HID on bt.org is broken (redirect to irrelevent page)